# Crontab every hour from 7 am to 12 pm

Tags: linux, cron

I need to run script every hour from 7 am to midnight (including midnight).

I've created this `crontab` but it didn't do anything at 7 and 8 am.

```
0 7-0/1 * * * ~/.venvs/p/bin/python ~/p/manage.py post_from_queue >> ~/p/logs/posts.log
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper format is :

```
0 0,7-23 * * * ~/.venvs/p/bin/python ~/p/manage.py post_from_queue >> ~/p/logs/posts.log
```

If this do not work on your case you should set two cron records:

```
0 7-23 * * * ~/.venvs/p/bin/python ~/p/manage.py post_from_queue >> ~/p/logs/posts.log
0 0 * * * ~/.venvs/p/bin/python ~/p/manage.py post_from_queue >> ~/p/logs/posts.log
```

It is wise to create script with the command above. And use absolute paths instead of relative

Comment: I'm not sure, it raises: "/tmp/crontab.e0WkNR/crontab":2: bad hour
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)